# Git doesnt show diff for some files in pull requests

Tags: java, css, git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I'm using Bitbucket for reviewing pull requests.

The files(happens to only css & jsp) shows modified but only shows first line modified & doesn't highlight actual changes. I literally have to get raw files from feature branch and remote branch to do comparison. 
I also later added a .gitattributes to force git to diff files as text instead of binary. I tried adding below in my .gitattributes file but that didn't seem to work.
In my .gitattributes file:

```
# Web
*.css     text diff=css
*.css     diff=css
```

Its likely a git issue as I tried fetching the pull request locally to my local branch and then compared with the remote branch and I noticed same problem as i see in Bitbucket.

Please help.

Comment: Out of the context but I would recommend you to use [smartgit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/download)

Comment: I'm confused, Git isn't showing you a correct diff, or BitBucket isn't showing you a correct diff?  Or both?

Comment: Both. I thought it was a bitbucket problem. But then i fetched the pull request locally into my local branch and then did a compare against remote branch. git fetch -> git checkout -b branchabc origin/branchabc -> git diff branch
 I saw the same problem.